# Quelles sont les différences entre un chiffre et un nombre ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, nombres

En français, je ne suis pas sur de bien comprendre la différence entre la notion de chiffre et de nombre.

J'entends souvent dire que 0, 1,..., 9 sont des **chiffres** et 87 c'est un **nombre** parce qu'il y a plusieurs chiffres.

Pourtant, d'après ce que je comprends (peut-être mal) de [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre):

- Le **nombre** est l'objet mathématique sur lequel on fait nos calculs.
- Les **chiffres** sont les symboles que l'on utilise pour représenter ces nombres.

Donc, 87 est-il un nombre ou un chiffre (ou un couple de chiffre) ?

Enfin, est-ce que π est un chiffre qui représente un nombre (la circonférence d'un cercle de diamètre 1) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between "numéro", "nombre" and "chiffre" in French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14471/the-difference-between-num%c3%a9ro-nombre-and-chiffre-in-french)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Il me semble qu'il y a déjà la plupart des éléments de réponse dans ta question.

Pour clarifier :

> **Un chiffre est un signe perceptible**, une convention arbitraire (un dessin ou une série de sons la plupart du temps) ayant un rôle particulier dans un système de représentation numérique. Pour chaque système, il y a une série déterminée de caractères qui sert à construire les représentations des nombres, et on appelle alors ces caractères des *chiffres*. En base 10, on a besoin de dix chiffres, et en français on utilise aujourd'hui pour ceci les chiffres arabes (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) *(il y a d'autres systèmes de représentation numérique comme le système hexadécimal bien connu en informatique utilisant 16 chiffres (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E), et même d'autres modes d'utilisation des caractères, bien sûr, comme les lettres qui composent les mots, par exemple)*
>   **Un nombre est une idée**, une abstraction mathématique que l'on peut représenter de plusieurs manières, notamment par des chiffres. Le cas que tu cites de la lettre π est un bon exemple d'une alternative à l'utilisation de chiffres : on peut représenter un nombre par une lettre, c'est une des bases de l'algèbre.

Et pour répondre plus spécifiquement aux interrogations de la fin de ta question :

- "87" est un nombre que l'on exprime, en base 10, avec deux chiffres. *(En base 100, un seul chiffre suffirait pour écrire ce nombre. En binaire, ce nombre s'exprime avec 7 chiffres : 1010111)*
- Le caractère "π" est utilisé, en tant que lettre, pour représenter en mathématique une fameuse constante un peu supérieure à 3, mais ce n'est **pas** un chiffre. *(Ecrire "25π0" ou "π,1" ne représente pas des nombres de manière valide.)*

Comment: Effectivement, si on introduit la notion de base, ça devient plus clair. 87, c'est bien deux chiffres distincts: 8 dizaines et 7 unités.

Comment: π n'est utilisé en tant que chiffre dans aucune représentation des nombres que je connaisse. C'est simplement une constante. Ok la correction est déjà faite, je vois :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Argh, je vois ton commentaire en éditant ma réponse ! Oui, je me suis rendu compte à l'instant que j'étais allé trop vite, c'est corrigé.

Comment: Je ne sais pas si ça peut clarifier ou embrouiller les choses, mais *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, *e*, *f* sont aussi des *chiffres* dans la représentation hexadécimale :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, tout-à-fait ! C'est bien ce que je voulais faire comprendre avec mon histoire de "87" en base 100. Arbitrairement, chaque système de représentation désigne les caractères qui sont valides pour construire les nombres et les appelle des chiffres. *0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9* ne sont que ceux de la base 10 auxquels nous sommes habitués dans le contexte courant.

Comment: Et l'expression "le nombre de fois que j'ai vu ma mére en train de boire" <*>? Pourquoi pas le numéro? Certainement pas le chiffre, mais pas  "une idée, une abstraction mathématique que l'on peut représenter de plusieurs manières, notamment par des chiffres" non plus? <*> example fictif, heureusement! :-)

Comment: On peut dire "les chiffres" comme digits en anglais, et "les nombres" comme numbers ?

Comment: @user39269 Yes, same usages.

Answer (score 6):

La différence est la même que celle entre une lettre et un mot. Un chiffre (respectivement une lettre) est un symbole servant, avec d'autres symboles, à écrire un nombre (respectivement un mot.) C'est un élément du premier ordre d'un langage, si tu veux une définition logicienne.

Comment: On peut alors parler de la lettre "a" et du mot "a" (indicatif présent du verbe avoir à la 3è personne du singulier), comme on peut parler du nombre 8 comme dans "il a volé 8 pommes" qui est écrit avec le chiffre 8.

Comment: Absolument, Bernard. Je pourrais même aller plus loin et dire que le nombre 16 = 6*1 + 1*0 est totalement indépendant de son écriture en base 10, on pourrait d'ailleurs l'écrire plutôt 1000 en base 2. La même anologie dans le contexte lettres/mots est valable, mais entraînerait plus de discussions sur les analogues éventuels de bases 10 ou 2 ou autres : langues/concepts différents ?

Comment: **Your answer appears flawed? [En particulier _chiffre_ peut signifier le résultat d'un calcul ou d'un dénombrement (auquel cas nombre ou somme lui est souvent substituable, chiffre ayant même alors à mon oreille un aspect vieilli pour ne pas dire désuet).](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13246) _Chiffre_ can also = [Le nombre indique l'aboutissement, le résultat d'un calcul](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49883).**

Comment: The only flaw that I see so far is that in some years "chiffre" will also be able to design a poney because a small group of people will start to use the word "chiffre" in that meaning. Not all "abus de langage" are bad, but you have to know the basic definitions and all abuses made of them. ;)

Answer (score 4):

En première acception, les chiffres sont aux nombres ce que les lettres sont aux mots.  Les premiers sont des signes qui assemblés permettent de représenter les seconds.

Mais [*chiffre*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/chiffre) et [*nombre*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/nombre) ont d'autres acceptions.  En particulier *chiffre* peut signifier le résultat d'un calcul ou d'un dénombrement (auquel cas *nombre* ou *somme* lui est souvent substituable, *chiffre* ayant même alors à mon oreille un aspect vieilli pour ne pas dire désuet).

Answer (score 1):

Il n’existe que dix chiffres: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.  Ce sont des signes, des symboles qui servent à écrire tous les nombres, comme les lettres de l’alphabet servent à écrire tous les mots du dictionnaire.

Les nombres représentent une quantité, une valeur et peuvent être écrits avec un ou plusieurs chiffres. L’ordre de lecture est important et on lit toujours de gauche à droite.

http://www.jerevise.fr/difference-chiffre-nombre.html

Comment: "Il n’existe que dix chiffres".  Et les chiffres romains?

Comment: Ah oui c'est un autre bon exemple les chiffres romains, c'est un comble que je n'en ai pas parlé dans ma réponse ^^

Comment: Dix chiffres : en base 10 (ce qui est le cas général ; je dois avouer que je pinaille), oui. En [hexadécimal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syst%C3%A8me_hexad%C3%A9cimal), A, B, C, D, E et F sont des chiffres également.

Answer (score -1):

Je vous conseille que ce n'est pas ma langue maternelle, mais c'est une chose que j'ai entendu où j'enseigne les maths: dans un niveau de langue familier, on dit parfois « chiffre » pour dire « nombre ». Le wiktionnaire l'affirme :

http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chiffre

Comment: Et j'ai toujours (34 ans d'enseignement des maths au Cégep) essayé de faire comprendre à mes élèves qu'il y a une différence.

Comment: @BernardMassé C'est même un euphémisme de dire qu'il y a *une différence* entre les deux. Ils n'ont strictement rien à voir. L'un fait partie du monde physique, l'autre est une idée. Un chiffre est totalement arbitraire, il est lié à une culture, à des techniques, et à des usages. Tout nombre est, quant à lui, universel, immuable et éternel.

Comment: bien que vous précisiez "dans un langage familier", la question porte sur les différences entre les deux, et pour moi, ces différences sont bien présentes.  -- 
Though you precise "in a casual language, the question was about the differences between the two, and those differences **do** exist.

Answer (score -3):

pi (mon clavier ne comporte pas le symbole) est une abstraction mathématique qui représente un nombre non réel, pi n'est pas un chiffre, tout comme 87 n'est pas un chiffre et 3,14 non plus ! 3,14 est un nombre décimal fini, composé des chiffres 3, 1, et 4. Pi n'est pas un nombre décimal et ne peut pas en être un puisqu'il n'est pas fini. (d'où sa qualification de "nombre infini").

Comment: C'est la première fois que j'entends parler de "pi" comme nombre infini. Il a une infinité de décimales, mais il a une valeur finie bien définie: il est le rapport constant (quelque soit le cercle) de la circonférence d'un cercle à son diamètre.

Comment: C'est dans ces situations que les mots ont un sens considérable ! "Infini" ne signifie pas "indéfini", "immensément grand" ou bien "variable". L'adjectif infini se rapporte à la finition du nom qualifié, comme son radical le laisse présumer. Quand on parle de l'infini comme de l'infiniment grand ou l'infiniment petit, on rapporte une mesure quelle qu'elle soit (masse, distance, force) à un nombre non fini, puisqu'on pourra toujours ajouter un chiffre au nombre le plus grand qu'on puisse imaginer. On définit donc "infini" une chose dont on ne peut pas définir de fin.

Comment: Ce n'est pas pour cela qu'il n'est pas défini, et qu'il n'a pas de valeur, comme vous l'avez si bien énoncé, c'est le rapport de la circonférence d'un cercle quelconque à son diamètre, ni d'approximation (3,14 pour les moins courageux).Il a même un très grand nombre de décimales connues à ce jour, grâce à la puissance de calcul de nos ordinateurs, mais il cette valeur n'est pas un nombre FINI.