# The difference between "numéro", "nombre" and "chiffre" in French

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, choix-de-mot

I want to know the difference between "numéro", "nombre" and "chiffre" in French because it seems they all mean "number" when it comes to English. I also want to know when they are used if they are different.

Comment: They don't all mean ["number"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/number) in English. You should consider, ["digit"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digit), ["figure"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/figure) and ["numeral"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/numeral) as well.

Comment: Note also that "Numéro" is a French homonym refering in a totally different context to an act. E.g. : "Circus act" = "Numéro de cirque"

Comment: Part of your question is already answered here: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13243

Comment: [Laure's answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14473/7224) is short and yet explicit. Basically, the usual translations would be "_chiffre_" = "digit", "_nombre_" = "number/figure", "_numéro_" = "number/#" ([Édouard](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14472/7224) made a note about the abbreviation).

Comment: @Chop **Your answer appears flawed? [En particulier _chiffre_ peut signifier le résultat d'un calcul ou d'un dénombrement (auquel cas nombre ou somme lui est souvent substituable, chiffre ayant même alors à mon oreille un aspect vieilli pour ne pas dire désuet).](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13246) _Chiffre_ can also = [Le nombre indique l'aboutissement, le résultat d'un calcul](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49883).**

Comment: @user1147844 This is not an answer, simply a quick summary (a comment, with limited length), to give some highlights. Also, consider that most questions here are asked by people who are learning French, and hope for simple answer, not dissertations. Going in depth in all the subtleties, nuances and complexities of the language might confuse more than it helps.

Answer (score 50):

Les **chiffres** sont des **signes** qui servent à écrire les nombres. Il y a 10 chiffres : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, et 9.

Les **nombres** représentent une **valeur**, une quantité.
Le nombre 1853 (mille huit cent cinquante-trois) s'écrit avec quatre chiffres.

Un **numéro** sert à **identifier**, à distinguer un élément parmi d'autre. Si je dis d'un sportif qu'il a le dossard numéro 4 ça implique que d'autres de l'équipe ont d'autres numéros. Un numéro peut être composé de chiffres mais pas uniquement, voir les numéros de plaques minéralogiques qui ont des lettres et des chiffres.

Comment: "plaques minéralogiques" ou plus couramment "plaque d'immatriculation" :)

Comment: Il s'agit de divers aspects du concept de quantité. Chiffre : aspect scriptural ; nombre : aspect cardinal ; numéro : aspect ordinal.

Answer (score 28):

A “numéro” is an identifier, usually made of digits. It’s a nominal number. If you were to abbreviate the “number” which correspond to “numéro”, you would usually use a hash sign, ‘#’. It is, in particular, used for phone numbers.

> *La commande numéro 173 est prête à la boucherie.*
>   Order number 173 is ready at the butcher’s counter.
>
> *Mon numéro de téléphone est le 01 23 45 67 89.*
>   My phone number is 01 23 45 67 89.

A “nombre” is a cardinal number, plain and simple. It’s used to *count* stuff.

> *Quel sera le nombre d’invité au dîner ?*
>   How many guests will there be at the dinner?

Finally, a “chiffre” is *not* a number. It’s a digit. A symbol used to write numbers, the equivalent of a letter for words if you will. Usually (i.e. when you use the [decimal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)), the “chiffres” are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9<sup>*</sup>.

> *En base décimale, le nombre quatre-vingt est représenté par le chiffre 8 suivi du chiffre 0 ; en base hexadécimale, par le chiffre 5 suivi du chiffre 0.*
>   In the decimal system, the number eighty is represented with the digit 8 flowed by the digit 0; in the hexadecimal system, by the digit 5 followed by the digit 0.

Note that, while “numéro” is clearly distinct in French, “chiffre” is often used instead of “nombre” by many natives. See, e.g., [Des chiffres et des lettres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_chiffres_et_des_lettres), which actually uses “nombres”.

---

<sup>*</sup> In hexadecimal, it would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E and F.

Comment: "La commande numéro 173 est prête à la boucherie." Mon cerveau a lu ça avec la voix du Colryut

Comment: @GillesV. Tous le monde ne connait pas [ces supermarchés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colruyt_%28France%29). ;)

Comment: Pour illustrer le raccourci parfois fait entre "chiffres" et "nombres" dans la langue courante, on peut citer l'expression "les chiffres du chômage" (mais "chiffres" est alors au pluriel, et se traduirait plutôt par "figure" que "digit"). Y a-t-il des exemples où on dirait "un chiffre" pour parler d'un nombre?

Comment: Je voulais dire "un chiffre" au singulier.

Comment: @GillesV Je savais que cet exemple ne laisserait pas indifférent. ;-)

Comment: @T.Verron Excellente remarque, je fouille dans mon Grevisse voir ce qu'il raconte à ce sujet.

Comment: So you claim the TV show should be called “Des nombres et des mots”? “Des chiffres et des lettres” is perfectly fine.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I almost wrote that too, but I realized that the proper name would actually be "des nombres et des lettres" : participants combine numbers as they combine letters.

Comment: [Barry Williams a soulevé un exemple intéressant](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14488/7224) où « chiffre » est préféré à « nombre » avec le même sens, ce qui appuie l'argument de @T.Verron. Contrairement à ce que j'ai moi-même dit dans un commentaire, [« _figure_ »](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/figure) se traduit plus volontiers par « chiffre » que par « nombre ». Pour [le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chiffre), il s'agit d'un usage familier.

Comment: @Chop: *chiffre d'affaire* parmi plein d'autres emplois ne me parait absolument pas familier.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai bien dit « pour le Wiktionnaire ». Ton exemple me paraît effectivement parfaitement valide.

Answer (score 3):

numéro = serial number

nombre = how many units, an integer number

chiffre = digit,   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Cet ensemble contient un nombre N d'objets
qui ont chacun un numéro entre 0 et N-1 
et pour N<10 ce numéro est à un seul chiffre.

Comment: Un nombre est-il nécessairement un entier ? Un décimal ou un irrationnel ne sont-ils pas des nombres également ?

Answer (score 1):

- Les chiffres: ils sont toujours: 0 ; 1 ; 2 ;  3 ; 4 ; 5 ; 6 ; 7 ; 8 ; 9
- Les nombres: ils sont formés de chiffres
- Les numéros: c'est une série de chiffres: beaucoup de chiffres, par exemple les numéros de téléphone

Comment: Et j'ai oublié de citer que les nombres peuvent aussi contenir des virgules

Comment: En quoi cette réponse est-elle meilleure que les autres ? En particulier https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14473/635

Comment: Un numéro ne comporte pas forcement beaucoup de chiffres, par exemple : j'habite au N° 7 de la rue Machin.

Answer (score -1):

OUI, chiffre peut vouloir dire nombre, comme dans « Ça chiffre », « Ça se chiffre à combien ? », « Dites-moi un chiffre !», « des chiffres et des lettres » déjà cité...

Nombre peut souvent être employé à la place de chiffre, comme dans « cette boule porte le nombre 3. »

Numéro représente presque toujours un ordinal, mais il y a des exceptions probablement (voir les plaques de voiture citées plus haut). Par contre, l'idée de « numéro » suppose que ce numéro SOIT affiché (à un moment où à un autre, pour le numéro 1 mondial, quand il monte sur le podium...)

Comment: Bonjour @stefjourdan. Fais attention lorsque tu écris une réponse : il faut laisser une ligne vide pour que StackExchange affiche un retour à la ligne. Par ailleurs, sans vouloir être à cheval sur la typographie, les points en fin de phrase aident à la lisibilité et la compréhension.

Comment: Concernant l'exemple de la boule, j'aurais plutôt utilisé « numéro » (par habitude de la boule numéro 8 au billard, peut-être).