# Sens spécifique du pluriel « chiffres »

Tags: sens, dictionnaires

Il me semble que le mot « chiffres » au pluriel peut avoir un sens spécifique, paradoxalement plus proche de *nombre* que de *chiffre*, celui d’un ensemble de nombres ou de statistiques.

Deux exemples tirés d’une recherche pour « les chiffres » sur un moteur de recherche d’actualités :

> *Les chiffres accablants du PSG en Ligue des champions*
>
> *Coronavirus en Belgique - Bilan du jour : voici les chiffres*

S’agit-il vraiment d’un sens spécifique, comme « travaux » par rapport à « travail » peut-être ?

Si oui, cette acception du terme est-elle documentée quelque part, dans un dictionnaire ou autre ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ce sens n'est pas spécifique au pluriel. On le retrouve au singulier quand on parle par exemple du chiffre d'affaire.

TLFi **[Chiffre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chiffre)**

> **I.−** [Sans idée de secret]
> **A.−** [Ce qui est marqué est un nombre]
> [...]
> **3.** [Le nombre indique l'aboutissement, le résultat d'un calcul]

Comment: En effet ! Merci.