# Why does « chiffre » (digits), NOT « nombre », mean "figure"?

Tags: différence

> [Les **chiffres** sont des **signes** qui servent à écrire les nombres. Il y a 10 chiffres : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, et 9](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14473)

I have long felt that *nombre* (NOT *chiffre*) ought to mean "figure" in English, because [Les nombres représentent une valeur, une quantité.](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14473) So why does *chiffre* mean "figure"? Digit differs from figure, because there are solely 10 [*chiffre*[s] = digit[s], 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14478), BUT figures refer to any real number. See

> - [Le nombre indique l'aboutissement, le résultat d'un calcul](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49883).

> - [En particulier *chiffre* peut signifier le résultat d'un calcul ou d'un dénombrement (auquel cas nombre ou somme lui est souvent substituable, chiffre ayant même alors à mon oreille un aspect vieilli pour ne pas dire désuet).](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13246)

In sentences below, can *nombre* replace all instances of *chiffre*, while keeping *chiffre*'s meaning of "figure"?

> [De plus, un autre problème majeur est que nous ne sommes
> pas en mesure de donner une image claire de la situation
> actuelle pour le paludisme en raison du manque de **chiffres**.
> Nous n'avons pas été capables de fournir le ***nombre*** précis des
> patients que nous avons traités aux ACT [traitements ä base
> de combinaisons de molécules incluant de l'artémisinine]
> ily a un an, et cela est toujours le cas aujourd'hui.  [⋯] Ne pas pouvoir founir des **chiffres** précis est un échec.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/M%C3%A9decins_Sans_Fronti%C3%A8res_%C3%89volution_d/sDSbDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22manque%20de%20chiffres%22&pg=PA350&printsec=frontcover)

> [La croissance du PIB étant négative pour un certain ***nombre*** de ces pays, tandis que la
> croissance démographique atteint 3 % pour la région, ces **chiffres** mini-
> misent la détérioration, et meme les pays réalisant les meilleures perfor-
> mances ont vu leurs dépenses par habitant stagner ou diminuer. Le
> manque de *chiffres* complique l'étude de la répartition des dépenses dans
> I'éducation, mais elles semblent étre en moyenne de 50 % pour l'enseignement primaire, 3()% pour I'enseignement secondaire et 20% pour l'enseignement supérieur.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/L_Afrique_maintenant/XJ3Db2_mGu0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22manque%20de%20chiffres%22&pg=PA177&printsec=frontcover)

> [Vous téléphonez diverses administrations pour obtenir
> une explication sur les raisons d'étre d'un tel désert statistique,
> peine perdue : invoquant le manque de personnel ou de temps, voire l'ordinateur malin, les fonctionnaires des divers offices
> communaux, cantonaux ou fédéraux regrettent tous le manque
> de **chiffres** utilisables, ou vous proposent, si tout va bien, de vous
> adresser å un organisme privé.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_perte_de_vue/IYRDdUmPJ_YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22manque%20de%20chiffres%22&pg=PA44&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: "chiffre(s)" is often used when referring to quantitative data (or their lack). It is then an amount, e.g. the total sum of an evaluation, as in "le chiffre de la population parisienne" or "Un petit trésor, de l'or et des billets de banque, dont il ne connaissait jamais le chiffre exact" (Zola, Le Docteur Pascal,1893, p. 44).

Comment: It's the same in English! “Figure” originally meant a digit (a narrowing from the more general meaning of one symbol which could be a letter, digit, ideogram, pictogram, …), then evolved to also mean a number (which can be written using multiple _figures_ in the earlier sense).

Comment: counter point: why use "figure", not "number" in English?

Comment: @njzk2 there's similar confusion and overlap in English. The terms aren't clear-cut in any of the two languages. https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/265324/170912

Comment: @njzk2 Ask this as a new separate question on https://english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: my point was to question why would it be surprising to use chiffres, and what would be the basis for wanting to use nombres.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't replace ***chiffres*** by *nombres* in the expression ***manque de chiffres***.

> Nous ne sommes pas en mesure [...] à cause du manque de nombres. ❌
> Les fonctionnaires regrettent le manque de nombres. ❌

These sentences would make no sense. There is an infinity of *nombres* so there can be no lack of them.

In the other sentence, ***nombre*** would be unidiomatic.

> Ces nombres minimisent la détérioration. ❓

A *nombre* is often the result of a ***dénombrement*** (counting) while a *chiffre*, in this acception, is the result of a ***calcul*** (calculation). Statistics better match the second definition.

As to why a word that means 'digit' ends up meaning 'figure', it is the usual fate of words to have their meanings evolve in the course of their lives. After all, ***chiffre*** (and 'cypher' for that matter) originally comes from a word meaning 'zero', and even actually cognates with *zéro* so it is simply a typical case of broadening of meanings: **zero → digit → figure**.

Comment: Interestingly, in English, "We don't have the numbers" can mean either (a) our number of [item]s is too low, e.g. we can't produce enough copies, or (b) we have not yet determined the values of a given set of variables. This latter is closest to *chiffre*, and in fact "We don't have the figures" can be substituted precisely for sense (b).

Comment: @LukeSawczak (a) On n'atteint pas les chiffres (prévus/attendus/espérés), (b) On n'a pas (encore) les chiffres.